# Is there an inverse image functor for sheaves on stacks?

Tags: sheaf-theory, stacks, lie-groupoids, differentiable-stacks

I'm interested specifically in an inverse image functor between differentiable stacks, ie. stacks coming from Lie groupoids. Specifically, if I have a morphism of Lie groupoids $H\to G$ and I have a sheaf on $G$ (obtained from a sheaf on the stack $[G^0/G]$) is there some kind of complex of sheaves on stacks I can associate to $H?$ I can always form the nerves of $H$ and $G$ and take the inverse image sheaf as simplicial manifolds, but this isn't what I want.